# Need to put a quiz into an array in C++

Tags: c++

I have written a simple tutorial for school and need to put the multiple choice questions and answers into an array. I have been taught how to use arrays for integers but not chars or strings and am left to figure it out on my own for this project. I have working code but am fairly sure I am not meeting the requirements. Is there a better way to create an array to store this quiz and the answers? I am very new to C++ and this is a lot of code, and I am sure it can be done better. Please just focus on the array portion and Thank You in advance for any inputs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define MAX_LENGTH 100
using namespace std;

void answer(int, int);

int main()
{
    char choice1;
    int a, b, c, d, input;
    char studentName[MAX_LENGTH] = { 0 };

    cout << "Hello new student, What is your name? " << endl;
    cin.getline(studentName, MAX_LENGTH);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Hello " << studentName << " welcome to my tutorial! " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Let me start by defining a variable, a variable is a way to store a value.\n"
        << "It is like a container that holds the value until needed. " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Variables are given names so that they can be called on in your program.\nWe name variables with a style of writing"
        << " called camel case.\nCamel case is using lower case letters for the first word of the name and a\n"
        << "capitol letter for the second word." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "An example of camel case would be variableName or studentName. " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Do you understand what a variable is? " << endl;
    cin >> choice1;
    if (toupper(choice1) == 'N')
    {
        cout << "Variables take input data and store it for later use in your code, "
            << " we name the variables and then call them by name. " << endl;
    }
    else if (toupper(choice1) == 'Y')
    {
        cout << "Great! Lets move on to inputs and outputs. " << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Inputs are the commands that tell the program what to do or process,"
        << " Outputs are what is done or displayed to the user" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please enter 3 numbers, lets have the program do some math for us. " << endl;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    d = a + b + c;
    cout << "The sum of these numbers is  " << d << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Syntax is the proper wording, spacing and indentation of the code that allows"
        << " the program to compile and run.\n " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Indentations keep commands contained within the line they are meant to run. " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Do you understand why syntax and indentations are important? " << endl;
    cin >> choice1;
    if (toupper(choice1) == 'N')
    {
        cout << "Without proper syntax and indentations the compiler won't know what to do with your code"
            << " and will return an error. " << endl;
    }
    else if (toupper(choice1) == 'Y')
    {
        cout << "Great! Lets move on to an example of a print statement. " << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Hello World is a simple program that is usually the first coding you will learn. " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "In order to process your program and get an output you must build and debug your code"
        << " using the tools in visual studio. " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "I want to test your knowledge! " << studentName << " Here is a short quiz." << endl;
    cout << endl;

    int choice, score = 0;
    char quiz1[] = { "A. What does a variable do in your program?" };
    char ans1[] = { "1. Stores a value" };
    char ans2[]{ "2. Starts a new line" };
    char ans3[]{ "3. Compiles your code" };
    char ans4[]{ "4. Breaks out of a loop" };
    cout << quiz1 << endl;
    cout << ans1 << endl;
    cout << ans2 << endl;
    cout << ans3 << endl;
    cout << ans4 << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    answer(choice, 1);

    char quiz2[] = { "B. What is syntax? " };
    char ans5[]{ "1. Syntax is the way you store a value " };
    char ans6[]{ "2. Syntax is a conditional statement " };
    char ans7[]{ "3. Syntax is the the proper wording and spacing of the program that allows it to run" };
    char ans8[]{ "4. Syntax does nothing in C++" };
    cout << quiz2 << endl;
    cout << ans5 << endl;
    cout << ans6 << endl;
    cout << ans7 << endl;
    cout << ans8 << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    answer(choice, 3);
    char quiz3[] = { "C. When naming variables what is the term for the type of writing used? " };
    char ans9[]{ "1. Camel Cares " };
    char ans10[]{"2. Dictation "};
    char ans11[]{"3. Caligrapy "};
    char ans12[]{"4. Camel Case"};
    cout << quiz3 << endl;
    cout << ans9 << endl;
    cout << ans10 << endl;
    cout << ans11 << endl;
    cout << ans12 << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    answer(choice, 4);

    void answer(int choice, int answer)
{
    if (choice == answer)
    {
        cout << "Well Done!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Sorry! You missed that one..." << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: In what exact way do you believe that you're "not meeting the requirements" and how?

Comment: When you start naming variables ans1 ... ansX you probably want to use an array or  vector.

Comment: Suggestion: make a structure that contains the question, its possible answers (an array of strings) and the correct answer. Then make an array of this structure and a function that uses the structure to ask the question and get and verify the user's answer.

Comment: Your code does not compile because of a missing `}` for `main`. You are including the wrong header, it should be `#include<<cctype>` instead of `#include<string>`. You are not using any `std::string` (from `#include<string>`) but `std::toupper` (from `#include<cctype>`). Instead of `char` arrays you *should* however use `std::string`. I am not sure what your instructors intention is. If they really want you to use `char` arrays that is a bad teaching approach imho. Has `std::string` been introduced to you?

Comment: We have not been taught to use strings in arrays only int arrays. I am totally in the dark on how to use string arrays and am trying to build this code from tutorials online and with help here on stack overflow. I think the school wants us to dig this out for ourselves but I agree that it seems a bit dodgy for them to toss us to the wolves like this.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs, I will try to add a function and an array to clean this up.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your inputs and guidance! I followed some of your suggestions and have a working code that meets the requirements for my school!
Here is what I have come up with as a solution to the array problem.

```
#include <iostream> //pre processor directives
#include <string>
#define MAX_LENGTH 100 // defines char length for student name input
using namespace std;
const int SIZE = 20; // sets size of password input
const int MIN = 8; // sets min size of password
int numCorrect; // int for score total
int ans; // int for score total


int validLength(char pwd[]); // array for password validation
void answer(int, int); // answer input function

int main()
{
    char choice1; // lines 22 - 25 sets parameters for tutorial portion of program
    int a, b, c, d, input;
    char studentName[MAX_LENGTH] = { 0 };
    int choice2 = 0;


    cout << "Hello new student, What is your name? " << endl; // gets input for student name stores in variable
    cin.getline(studentName, MAX_LENGTH);
    cout << endl;
    char password[SIZE];
    while (true) //infinite while loop until password conditions met
    {
        cout << "Please create a password with at least 8 characters: " << endl;
        cin.getline(password, SIZE);
        if (validLength(password) == 1)
        {
            cout << "Password is valid and accepted! " << endl;
            cout << endl;
            break; // if password is valid breaks out of while loop
        }
        else;
        {
            cout << "Invalid Password, Please follow instructions: " << endl; // gives user error message and loops back to input
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    while (choice2 != 3) // infinite while loop until exit program is selected
    {
        cout << "Program Menu\n1. Tutorial\n2. Take Quiz\n3. Exit Program " << endl; // menu to user
        cin >> choice2;
        cout << endl;

        if (choice2 == 1) // conditional statement to start tutorial
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Hello " << studentName << " welcome to my tutorial! " << endl;
            cout << "Let me start by defining a variable, a variable is a way to store a value.\n"
                << "It is like a container that holds the value until needed. " << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Variables are given names so that they can be called on in your program.\nWe name variables with a style of writing"
                << " called camel case.\nCamel case is using lower case letters for the first word of the name and a\n"
                << "capitol letter for the second word." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "An example of camel case would be variableName or studentName. " << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Do you understand what a variable is? " << endl;
            cin >> choice1;
            if (toupper(choice1) == 'N')
            {
                cout << "Variables take input data and store it for later use in your code, " // conditional statements and outputs
                    << " we name the variables and then call them by name. " << endl;
            }
            else if (toupper(choice1) == 'Y')
            {
                cout << "Great! Lets move on to inputs and outputs. " << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Inputs are the commands that tell the program what to do or process,"
                << " Outputs are what is done or displayed to the user" << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Please enter 3 numbers, lets have the program do some math for us. " << endl; // simple math calculator
            cin >> a >> b >> c;
            d = a + b + c;
            cout << "The sum of these numbers is  " << d << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Syntax is the proper wording, spacing and indentation of the code that allows"
                << " the program to compile and run.\n " << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Indentations keep commands contained within the line they are meant to run. " << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Do you understand why syntax and indentations are important? " << endl;
            cin >> choice1;
            if (toupper(choice1) == 'N')
            {
                cout << "Without proper syntax and indentations the compiler won't know what to do with your code" // conditional statements
                    << " and will return an error. " << endl;
            }
            else if (toupper(choice1) == 'Y')
            {
                cout << "Great! Lets move on to an example of a print statement. " << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Hello World is a simple program that is usually the first coding you will learn. " << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "In order to process your program and get an output you must build and debug your code"
                << " using the tools in visual studio. " << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Now I would like to explain an array." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "An array is a way to store multiple values like a grocery list, a set of numbers or even text." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Variables can only store one value so arrays are a more efficient way to store values" << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Do you understand arrays? " << endl;
            cin >> choice1;
            if (toupper(choice1) == 'N') // conditional statements
            {
                cout << "Arrays store many values and the values can be accessed as a whole or individually. " << endl;
                cout << endl;
            }
            else if (toupper(choice1) == 'Y')
            {
                cout << "Great! How about a short quiz? " << endl;
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
        if (choice2 == 2) // conditional statement to start quiz
        {
            cout << "I want to test your knowledge! " << studentName << " here is a short quiz." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            int choice, score = 0;
            // string arrays for quiz
            string quizOne[5] = { "A. What does a variable do in your program?","1. Stores a value","2. Starts a new line",
                "3. Compiles your code","4. Breaks out of a loop"};
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            { 
                cout << quizOne[i] << endl;
            }
            cin >> choice;
            answer(choice, 1);
            if (choice == 1)
            {
                ans = 0;
                ans = ans + 1; // starts tallying correct answers to quiz
            }
            cout << endl;

            string quizTwo[5] = { "B. What is syntax?", "1. Syntax is the way you store a value","2. Syntax is a conditional statement ",
                "3. Syntax is the the proper wording and spacing of the program that allows it to run","4. Syntax does nothing in C++"};
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            { 
                cout << quizTwo[i] << endl;
            }
            cin >> choice;
            answer(choice, 3);
            if (choice == 3)
            {
                ans = ans + 1;
            }
            cout << endl;

            string quizThree[5] = { "C. When naming variables what is the term for the type of writing used?","1. Camel Cares",
                "2. Dictation","3. Caligraphy","4. Camel Case"};
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            { 
                cout << quizThree[i] << endl;
            }
            cin >> choice;
            answer(choice, 4);
            cout << endl;
            if (choice == 4)
            {
                ans = ans + 1;
            }

            numCorrect = ans; // stores number of correct answers in variable ans
            if (ans == 3)
            {
                cout << "You got 100 percent correct! Great Job! " << endl; // outputs to user total score
                cout << endl;
            }
            else
                cout << "You answered " << ans << " of the questions correctly" << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
        else if (choice2 == 3) // conditional statement to end program
        {
            cout << "Exiting Program" << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void answer(int choice, int answer) // function call to output if answer to quiz is correct or not
{
    if (choice == answer)
    {
        cout << "Well Done!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Sorry! You missed that one..." << endl;
    }
}
int validLength(char pwd[]) // function call to validate password length
{
    bool minLength = false;
    int length = strlen(pwd);
    if (length >= MIN)
    {
        minLength = true;
    }
    if (minLength == true)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```